# Wrong result in multiplying in javascript

Tags: javascript, multiplication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

I have two variables

```
var first : float = 200;
var next : float;
next = first * 1.2;
```

and when i write in debug log "next" it gives 40,00002. any advices?

Comment: Are you sure the code you posted is JS?

Comment: This is not the javascript syntax !!!, this is maybe actionscript or something else

Comment: Where did you get the syntax first : float from? JavaScript doesn't define types. like that...

Comment: `40,00002` really? Not `240,00002`? (but even that is strange as demonstrated by Adil in his answer).

Answer (score 2):

The precision of floating point computations is only as precise as the precision (no of bits and mantissa) it uses.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Machine_precision_and_backward_error_analysis

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem

Answer (score 2):

This give you 240. I think your are not not following the standard. I even parsed it with float

```
var first =parseFloat(200.0);
var next ;
next = parseFloat(first * 1.2);
alert(next);
```

​

```
​
```